# Pyplot to plot scatter distributions with colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, scatter

I have three one dimensional arrays that have same shape:
Array A has values range from 8.0 to 12.0, array B has values range from 0.5 to 2.0, array C has values ranges from 20 to 320. 
Now I want to plot scatter distribution: values in A as x axis, values in B as y axis and each dot has color that corresponds to value in C.
I tried this:

```
ax2.scatter(A, B, c=C/320.0,s=7,marker='.',edgecolor='none')
```

The plot is shown as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRvac.png), but I prefer it shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8U3c.png). How can I achieve this? Besides, how can I add the color bar as the examples shown. Also I want the color corresponds to C's values in log space instead of linear space. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `cmap` parameter. Your code should look like:

```
ax2.scatter(A, B, c=C, s=7, marker='.', cmap='Blues')
```

You can choose any of the cmaps listed here: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

For showing the colorbar you will need to add an extra line:

```
plt.colorbar()
```

Comment: For having the colors in log space you can simply pass `np.log(C)` to the `c` argument. I am not sure why you are getting that error, how are you initializing your plot ?